# Pyspark: filter last 3 days of data based on regex

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with dates and would like to filter for the last 3 days (not based on current time but the latest time available in the dataset)

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|id |partition                                                                         |date      |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|1  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-12-01/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-12-01|
|2  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-30/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-11-30|
|3  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-29/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-11-29|
|4  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-28/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-11-28|
|5  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-27/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-11-27|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Should return

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|id |partition                                                                         |date      |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|1  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-12-01/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-12-01|
|2  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-30/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-11-30|
|3  |/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-29/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl|2019-11-29|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

EDIT: I have taken @Lamanus answer to extract the dates from the partition string

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, '/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-12-01/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl'),
    (2, '/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-30/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl'),
    (3, '/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-29/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl'),
    (4, '/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-28/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl'),
    (5, '/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-11-27/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl')
], ['id','partition'])

df.withColumn('date', F.regexp_extract('partition', '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', 0)) \
  .show(10, False)
```

Comment: is your partition path is the data path of the dataframe or just string of column? confused.

Comment: sorry that is just a string of the column

Answer (score 1):

For your original purpose, I don't think you need the date-specific folders. Because the folder structure is already partitioned by `dt`, take them all and do the filter.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', '/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-12-01/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl')]).toDF('id', 'value')

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

dates = df.withColumn('date', regexp_extract('value', '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', 0)) \
  .withColumn('date', explode(sequence(to_date('date'), date_sub('date', 2)))) \
  .select('date').rdd.map(lambda x: str(x[0])).collect()

path = df.withColumn('value', split('value', '/dt')[0]) \
  .select('value').rdd.map(lambda x: str(x[0])).collect()

newDF = spark.read.json(path).filter(col(dt).isin(dates))
```

---

Here is my try.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', '/raw/gsec/qradar/flows/dt=2019-12-01/hour=00/1585218406613_flows_20191201_00.jsonl')]).toDF('id', 'value')

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('date', regexp_extract('value', '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', 0)) \
  .withColumn('date', explode(sequence(to_date('date'), date_sub('date', 2)))) \
  .withColumn('value', concat(lit('.*/'), col('date'), lit('/.*'))).show(10, False)

+---+----------------+----------+
|id |value           |date      |
+---+----------------+----------+
|1  |.*/2019-12-01/.*|2019-12-01|
|1  |.*/2019-11-30/.*|2019-11-30|
|1  |.*/2019-11-29/.*|2019-11-29|
+---+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: hi, I have edited my question sorry for the confusion. I think you already added some great components  I needed but would also need to select only the last 3 days of data.

Comment: Another approach.

Comment: I don't need to explode. all I try to do is to extract the date from the partition string (done with regexp_extract) and then select the last 3 days of data. Tried to edit my question to illustrate it